# Chemfig - chemnames too long and overlap

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chemfig

I have the following chemical equation in Chemfigs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
      \chemnameinit{[:-30]-[:30](-[2,0.6]Cl)(-[6,0.6])-[:-30]}
    \schemestart
    \chemname
    {\chemfig{[:-30]-[:30](-[2,0.6]OH)(-[6,0.6])-[:-30]}}
    {2-methylpropan-2-ol}
    \+
    \chemname
    {\chemfig{HCl}}
    {hydrochloric acid}
    \arrow{->}
    \arrow{0}[0,0.5]
    \chemname
    {\chemfig{[:-30]-[:30](-[2,0.6]Cl)(-[6,0.6])-[:-30]}}
    {2-chloro-2-methylpropane}
    \+
    \chemname
    {\ce{H2O}}
    {Water}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

This creates names that are really long and overlap:

[image: result]

I want to ensure that the chemical names are fully visible. I've tried using invisible arrows but that just messes vertical alignment up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: I took the liberty to extend your code to a working example, feel free to revert if it does not reflect the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some horizontal spacing via `\hspace{<dim>}`, `\qquad` etc. around the `\+`s and arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
      \chemnameinit{[:-30]-[:30](-[2,0.6]Cl)(-[6,0.6])-[:-30]}
    \schemestart
    \chemname
    {\chemfig{[:-30]-[:30](-[2,0.6]OH)(-[6,0.6])-[:-30]}}
    {2-methylpropan-2-ol}
    \hspace{1em}
    \+
    \hspace{2em}
    \chemname
    {\chemfig{HCl}}
    {hydrochloric acid}
    \hspace{1.5em}
    \arrow{->}
    \hspace{0.5em}
    \chemname
    {\chemfig{[:-30]-[:30](-[2,0.6]Cl)(-[6,0.6])-[:-30]}}
    {2-chloro-2-methylpropane}
    \hspace{1em}
    \+
    \hspace{0.5em}
    \chemname
    {\ce{H2O}}
    {Water}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]